# Как передать значение value через onclick?

Tags: javascript

как передать значение value через onclick

```
function price_do(priceone) {
    price_from.value = priceone;                    
    document.getElementById("price_to_one").innerHTML = '<div class="panel-tag">Цена от '+ priceone +'<i value="500" onclick="deleTe(this.value)">×</i><div>';                                  
}

function deleTe(this.value){
    alert(this.value);
}
```

Comment: У `i` не может быть атрибута `value`. Используйте `<i data-value="500" onclick="deleTe(this)">×</i><div>` и `function deleTe(q){ alert(q.getAttribute('data-value')); }`

Comment: Спасибо работает. Не могли бы объяснить, что вы сделали?

Comment: 1) Заменяем `value` у `<i>` на `data-value`. 2) По клику на элементе в функцию передаем весь объект. 3) В функции читаем нужный атрибут.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!